# heroku H10 issue

Tags: django, heroku

I am geting the Error:

```bash
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiz-iu.herokuapp.com request_id=9ee6412c-b248-4eeb-8eba-066f07b38a4f
 fwd="93.201.118.59" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-19T17:47:36.743985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quiz-iu.herokuapp.com request_id=071363bb-8ce2-4eed-bdc5-93cd3b39581f fwd="93.201.118.59" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

And if I set into the consul : heroku run rails console,
I get: bash: line 1: rails: command not found
Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to confirm:

1. Make sure that `git` is initialized in the same directory where the `manage.py` file is located.
2. Make sure that the `Procfile` is written with the capital `P` and the rest in small letters, as written in this sentence.
3. Make sure that the `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`, and `runtime.txt` (if you have one) are in the same directory as the `manage.py` file.
4. Copy-paste the following line as it is in your `Procfile` and replace `djangoheroku` with the name of your Django project.

```
web: gunicorn djangoheroku.wsgi --log-file -
```

> **Note**: Don't forget to replace `djangoheroku` with the name of your Django project.